# Geometric interpretation of length function of a coxeter group

Tags: group-theory, coxeter-groups

It is about an exercise in Humphrey's Reflection groups and Coxeter groups exercise 1 section 5.6. Let (W,S) be a Coxeter system. It is assumed throughout the chapter that S is finite. Let $\sigma :  W \rightarrow GL(V) $ be the geometric representation of W.  The exercise is

If W is infinite then the length function takes arbitrarily large values and so the root system $\Phi$ is infinite. I was able to prove this result.

Ans: Since the generating set S is finite there are only finitely many words of a particular length and so W is infinite will occur only when the length function takes arbitrarily large values. Since $\Phi=\{w(\alpha_s): w \in W, s \in S\}$ it follows that $\Phi$ is infinite.

My doubt is from this how it follows that $-1 \in GL(V)$ does not lie in $\sigma(W)$. Please help me to figure out this.

Comment: This follows from the fact that the length of $w$ is equal to the number of positive roots that are sent to negative roots.

Comment: I am sorry. I couldn't follow. Can you please elaborate little more?

Comment: So it is not possible for any element to map infinitely many positive roots to negative roots. So if $\Phi$ is infinite, then we cannot have $-1 \in {\rm GL}(V)$.